# MT5 Ichimoku SpanA cross SpanB

Tags: mql5

I have successfully found all my critical values for my Ichimoku strategy. I am missing the SpanA crossing element.

Doing a SpanA>SpanB is not the answer because this may be true and the trend may be nearing exhaustion. I would need to know when the lines crossed it would have to be a recent event to go along with my other conditions.

Below is not the full code as that would encompass many files. But the logic and condition I am looking for is in the if statements below

```
    #ifdef __MQL5__
        double  buf[];
        ArraySetAsSeries(buf, true);
        CopyBuffer(mHandle, SENKOUSPANA_LINE, -26, 56, buf); //Leading SpanA -26 captures begining of cloud
        double  spanAF  =   buf[1]; // 1 Front of cloud
        double   spanAch  =  buf[4];
        double  spanAC  =   buf[27];
        double  spanAP  =   buf[52];
        //double   spanAlag =  buf[1]; //51
        CopyBuffer(mHandle, SENKOUSPANB_LINE, -26, 56, buf); //Leading SpanB 52 units 
        double  spanBF  =   buf[1];
        double  spanBch =   buf[4]; 
        double  spanBC  =   buf[27];
        double   spanBP   =  buf[52]; //51
        CopyBuffer(mHandle,TENKANSEN_LINE,0,3,buf);       //Conversion Line
        double ConvLine = buf[1];
        CopyBuffer(mHandle,KIJUNSEN_LINE,0,3,buf);        //Base Line 26 periods
        double BaseLine = buf[1];
        CopyBuffer(mHandle,CHIKOUSPAN_LINE,0,28,buf);      //Lagging indicator
        double LagLine = buf[27];
        
    #endif 
    
    //  Closing prices
    double  close1  =   iClose(mSymbol, mTimeframe, 1);
    double  close2  =   iClose(mSymbol, mTimeframe, 2);

    double  tp  =   spanBC;
    //double    sl  =   (spanA1<spanB) ?
    //                      (mLastTick.bid*2)-spanB :
    //                      (mLastTick.ask*2)-spanB;
    
    double tpb = iClose(mSymbol, mTimeframe, 0) +.00200;
    double slb = iClose(mSymbol, mTimeframe, 0) -.00200;

    double tps = iClose(mSymbol, mTimeframe, 0) -.00200;
    double sls = iClose(mSymbol, mTimeframe, 0) +.00100;
    

    
    if (PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE) == POSITION_TYPE_BUY )
     {
      tp = tpb;
     }

    if (PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE) == POSITION_TYPE_SELL )
     {
      tp = tps;
     }
    
    
    
    Recount();
    if (mCount>0) {
        UpdateTPSL(tp);
        Recount();
    }
    
    if (mCount>0) return;   // Test again in case of close above
    

    

    if(close1>spanAC && close1>spanBC && ConvLine > BaseLine && LagLine > spanAP  && LagLine > spanBP && spanAF>spanBF ){
        Trade.Buy(mOrderSize, mSymbol, 0, slb, tpb, mTradeComment);
    } else

    if(close1<spanAC && close1<spanBC && ConvLine < BaseLine && LagLine < spanAP  && LagLine < spanBP && spanAF<spanBF ){
        Trade.Sell(mOrderSize, mSymbol, 0, sls, tps, mTradeComment);
    }

    return;
```

Basically the part I am missing is the recent change in the cloud. But the function works on a bar by bar basis. How would I be able to track the cloud change in this context so I can check to see if condition has been met along with all the other conditions. This is the only condition that needs time to develop.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of doing this was a loop. I did hard code the 256 not sure how to get the array size of buffer array. For the most part this loop with flag did the trick. If there is a more elegant way to do this please post.

```
int crossover;
crossover = -1;
for(int i=1;i<=256;i++){

//bullish
if(bufA[i-1]>bufB[i-1] && bufA[i]<=bufB[i]){
   Print("SpanA0: ",bufA[i-1]," SpanB0: ",bufB[i-1]," SpanA1: ",bufA[i]," SpanB1: ",bufB[i]);
   crossover = i;
   dt = 1;
   break;
   }

//bearish
if(bufA[i-1]<=bufB[i-1] && bufA[i]>bufB[i]){
   Print("SpanA0: ",bufA[i-1]," SpanB0: ",bufB[i-1]," SpanA1: ",bufA[i]," SpanB1: ",bufB[i]);
   crossover = i;
   ut = 1;
   break;
   }
```